# Mocking MatSnackBar in Angular 8 & Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx

I have an Angular 8 application that uses the Angular Material `MatSnackBar` and I am trying to test that the `open()` method of the class is called. The call to the `open()` method is within the body of an NgRx store selector, like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.dispatch(fromStore.getFeaturedPlaylists());

  this.subscription = this.store.pipe(
    select(fromStore.selectError),
    filter(err => !!err),
    switchMap((err) => this.snackBar.open(
      `Error: ${err.message}`,
      'Try again',
      {duration: 5000}).afterDismissed())
  ).subscribe(() => this.store.dispatch(fromStore.getFeaturedPlaylists()));
}
```

The relevant part of my test looks like this:

```
describe('FeaturedPlaylistsComponent', () => {

  let component: FeaturedPlaylistsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FeaturedPlaylistsComponent>;
  let matSnackBarSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatSnackBar>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatSnackBar', ['open']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        // other declarations here
        FeaturedPlaylistsComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        // other providers here
        {provide: MatSnackBar, useValue: spy}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    matSnackBarSpy = TestBed.get<MatSnackBar>(MatSnackBar);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FeaturedPlaylistsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('#ngOnInit()', () => { // fails
    // lots of other test...
    it('should call MatSnackBar.open() on error', () => {
      const error = new HttpErrorResponse({error: 'Some error'});

      component.ngOnInit();
      store.dispatch(fromStore.setError({error}));

      expect(matSnackBarSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

});
```

Now I know that this `ngOnInit()` function is working because I have another test that tests that the `getFeaturedPlayists()` action is dispatched twice: once on the first line of the function and once in the `subscribe` block:

```
it('should dispatch a getFeaturedPlaylists() action on error', () => { // succeeds
  const spy = spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
  const error = new HttpErrorResponse({error: 'Some error'});

  component.ngOnInit();
  store.dispatch(fromStore.setError({error}));

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  expect(spy.calls.allArgs()).toEqual([
    [fromStore.getFeaturedPlaylists()],
    [fromStore.setError({error})]
  ]);
});
```

To be honest I'm surprised that this test works: I would have assumed that I would need a `tick(5000)` to wait for the dialog to be dismissed, so perhaps there is actually something more sinister going on here.

Another thing: if I move the `open()` call to the first line of the function, like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.snackBar.open(
    `Error: Some error`,
    'Try again',
    {duration: 5000});
  // this.store.dispatch(fromStore.getFeaturedPlaylists());

  // this.subscription = this.store.pipe(
  //   select(fromStore.selectError),
  //   filter(err => !!err),
  //   switchMap((err) => this.snackBar.open(
  //     `Error: ${err.message}`,
  //     'Try again',
  //     {duration: 5000}).afterDismissed())
  // ).subscribe(() => this.store.dispatch(fromStore.getFeaturedPlaylists()));
}
```

the `should call MatSnackBar.open() on error` test works, so my understanding is that it is something to do with the call to `open()` being within this store selector.

Can anyone tell me why the `should dispatch a getFeaturedPlaylists() action on error` test works and the `should call MatSnackBar.open() on error` test doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized that I was using a mock store so no selectors were actually working. Using the real store for these tests, and with a little fiddling, I got them to work.

Comment: Hi I am also in the need to test exactly like your code.. Can you kindly give me tests that you have worked and it was fully working for the above code ? I am really stucked for too long as I am new to testing in angular..

Comment: I am getting error ```Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.``` for this line ```expect(matSnackBarSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalled();``` ..