# Test angular snackbar

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am making a simple snackbar for which code as follows,

**app.component.ts:**

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataService.valueChanges.pipe(
        filter((data) =>data=== true),
        switchMap(() => {
          const snackBarRef = this.matSnackBar.open(
            'A new value updated',
            'OK',
            {
              duration: 3000
            }
          );

          return snackBarRef.onAction();
        })
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.window.location.reload();
      });
  }
```

**app.component.spec.ts** (Including mock data for service)

```
describe('AppComponent', () => { 
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let matSnackBarSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatSnackBar>;

  let a = "";
  let b = "";
  let c = "";

  const mockDataService = {
    valueChanges: of(true)
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

    a = "Test";
    b = "X";
    c = "suc";
    matSnackBarSpy = TestBed.get<MatSnackBar>(MatSnackBar);

 })
}))

  describe('#ngOnInit()', () => {

    it('should call MatSnackBar.open()', async(done: DoneFn) => {
      const error = new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'Some error' });

      component.ngOnInit();

      expect(mockDataService.valueChanges).toBeTruthy();
      expect(matSnackBarSpy.open(a,b,c)).toBeTruthy();

      done();
    });
  });

})
```

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class DataService {
  valueChanges: Observable<boolean>;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- I am having a service which has the property `valueChanges` with type as `Observable<boolean>` .
- In `component.ts`, I am getting the value change as like mentioned above and end result I receive is boolean value `true` and also snackbar gets opened and everything is working fine.
- Now I am into implementation of test cases for the above like in `compoenent.spec.ts`,

  ```
    expect(mockDataService.valueChanges).toBeTruthy();
    expect(matSnackBarSpy.open(a,b,c)).toBeTruthy();
  ```

This results in success case but I am forever receiving this below output in chrome.

[image]

- But I have tried this with ref to [Mocking MatSnackBar in Angular 8 & Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429612/mocking-matsnackbar-in-angular-8-jasmine) but it doesn't helps.

**Requirement**: Need to cover all the tests that currently shows warning/indication of not covered in the above image..

Above test cases are running but test coverage shows still **function not covered** and also **statement not covered** warning when we open `index.html` of the component.

Comment: I'm not fully following. Question, what tool is telling you that the above in pink is not covered by testing? Also, you wouldn't want to cover matSnackbar's open method, because you didn't write it. The folks that develop that library have tests for that. What are you trying to accomplish with your testing? If it's only 100% code coverage, I don't think that's going to do what you think it is.  You might want to rethink how you're testing. Have a look at these https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html https://martinfowler.com/testing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you basically should test whether `matSnackBar` methods are called properly or not. Testing behavior of `matSnackBar` is not a unit testing.

Try

```
class MatSnackBarStub{
  open(){
    return {
      onAction: () => of({})
    };
  }

}
```

in `component.spec` file

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SomeComponent],
      providers: [{provide: MatSnackBar , useClass: MatSnackBarStub}]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    spyOn(component.matSnackBar,"open").and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.matSnackBar.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // you can also use ".toHaveBeenCalledWith" with necessary params
  });
```

I would suggest you to take a look at [this collection of articles](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7) related to unit testing using jasmine and karma. There is one article on how to use stubs and spies. I hope this would help

Comment: Could you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62130441/13270726 .. I am stucked heavily .. And I can see many of your posts related to testing in angular and I believe you will be able to provide right solution for me in that question.. Please help me..

Comment: @Undefined: Sure. Give me an hour. I'll write down an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Hoping for your good working solution..

Comment: Hi Vivek, Sorry for coming back again, Could you please help me to cover the test for this https://stackoverflow.com/q/62153001/13270726 .. Meanwhile I have made Team Lead to accept the solution given by you of implementing the service way..