# How to cover test for button click in angular? (Stackblitz attached)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am making a very simple application which has one input box and a button.

1. Input is for entering **email**
2. Subscribe **button** with event handler

Entering email and click over the button will make an api call, (This method works)

```
  subscribeEmail() {
    this.error = '';


        if (this.userForm.controls.email.status === 'VALID') {

      const params = new HttpParams()
                .set('EMAIL', this.userForm.controls.email.value)
        .set('subscribe','Subscribe')
        .set('b_aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d_01681f1b55','')
      console.log(params);
            const mailChimpUrl = this.mailChimpEndpoint + params.toString();

            this.http.jsonp<MailChimpResponse>(mailChimpUrl, 'c').subscribe(response => {
        console.log('response ', response)
                if (response.result && response.result !== 'error') {
                    this.submitted = true;
                }
                else {
                    this.error = response.msg;
                }
            }, error => {
                console.error(error);
                this.error = 'Sorry, an error occurred.';
            });
        }
  }
```

[**A complete working example here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsonp-riatjf)

There is no issues with it and you can also check everything works fine.

**Requirement:** I am in the need to cover test case for this button click and the http call with params.

I am unable to write the test case and it is showing that the tests are not covered for the http calls with params.

[image]

The tests that I have written so for for achieving the button click scenario like,

```
describe('HelloComponent', () => {

  let component: HelloComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HelloComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [HelloComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HelloComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('check subscribeEmail function has value', (done: DoneFn) => {

    const subscribeButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.subscribe'));
    subscribeButton.triggerEventHandler('click', {});

    done();
  });
});
```

And the [**Working stackblitz with test cases here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-qdernl)

(Please look into **hello.component.spec.ts** )

For button click, I have covered and it works

```
    const subscribeButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.subscribe'));
    subscribeButton.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
```

Could you please help me to achieve the result of covering the test case for the button click that has http call with params?

**Update:**
After some search I have found that I can use httpmock to call the url with params but I am ending up with error as,

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL:
>   https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&id=01681f1b55&amp",
>   found none.

You can also see the [**Modified stackblitz with httpMock here...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-9uvra9)

After all try only I am making this post so please consider this question and provide right solution.

A big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a very long question, I understand that you have put a lot of time to create it. So, I have also put some time to refactor the code to make it as per the best practices. This would require to split your code as a service and make the code better for Unit Testing. (Unit testing for **component** & **service**)

1. Create a service such as `MyService` and move the `http` code into it. It would help you unit test `component` and `service` separately. I created as below:

```
export class MyService {
  mailChimpEndpoint = 'https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&amp;id=01681f1b55&amp';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  submitForm(email: string){
    const params = new HttpParams()
                .set('EMAIL', email)
        .set('subscribe','Subscribe')
        .set('b_aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d_01681f1b55','')
    const mailChimpUrl = this.mailChimpEndpoint + params.toString();

    return this._http.jsonp<MailChimpResponse>(mailChimpUrl, 'c')
  }
}
```

2. Create a Unit test for component [as you can see here in the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-huyx9q?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts) . Take a good look at refactored code & how I have covered all cases depending on the scenario. As I have already explained in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929570/test-angular-snackbar/61984849), you can test `MatSnackBar` calls
3. Similarly, you can write Unit test for service by referring to [one my of my articles to test a service](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-services-in-angular-karma-ed49f8d5b264)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Few issues I am facing in my real app implementation. Please follow below comments..

Comment: I am continuously getting the error as ```Expected spy submitForm to have been called with [ 'test@gmail.com' ] but it was never called.``` and after hours of debugging I found that I am adding button ```disabled``` condition like, ```[disabled]="userForm.invalid || submitted"``` .. Also the same stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-krnuvg

Comment: Also I would like to know whether it is not possible to achieve the result without using service? Because for service a separate test file needs to created and it needs to be covered..

Comment: @Undefined: Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-k6xeyr?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts. U need to put `fixture.detectChanges()` after the `inpue.dispatch` event has been called.  Regarding creation of extra file for a service, that is a best practice. I would recommend you to do that. To mock without creating service file, did u try my "testing angular services" link ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and solution and this works fine.. Regarding the service yes I gone through your link but my Team Lead doesn't want me to create a new service for this and wants me to do in the same component file..

Comment: Please help me to create the tests in component file alone without service.. For sure I am going to accept your solution as you helped me a lot in understanding testing and hope you will help me in future as well.. If you help to create tests for component alone without adding a extra service then that would be really great for me..

Comment: @Undefined: Take a quick testing way as you are asking https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-dzxfyr?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts .  Best of luck with that lead :D

Comment: Thanks for your effort and help and much appreciated one Vivek..

Comment: Hi Vivek, Can you help me in this stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-ajoov8 I have written test case for service file with referring your link but stucked up here..

Comment: Also I will post the question regarding it soon and will share the link.. But could you please help me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I have posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62167637/13270726 and please consider the question and help me..

Comment: @Undefined: sure, give me 1-2 hrs. I'll try to provide a solution

Comment: Hi Vivek, Did you get chance to look at the question? I am waiting for your solution.. Also if you have time then please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/q/62153001/13270726 as well.. But the one which I have shared in the above comment is important(Testing of service)..

Comment: There is zero mentioning of  'button' or  'click' in this answer.

Comment: @minusone: There is. you need to look into the attached stackblitz link where I mentioned `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.subscribe')).nativeElement.click();`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it would be better to re-factory the code and make it more test friendly.
But the provided example still could be covered with tests. The idea to verify the passed parameters and if parameters are correct then return a predictable response as an observable.

so, the this.http.jsonp returns the expected result only if passed parameters are correct.

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement, Injector }  from '@angular/core';

import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { moqInjectorProviders, resolveMock } from 'ng-auto-moq';
import { Mock, It } from 'moq.ts';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { cold, getTestScheduler } from 'jasmine-marbles';


describe('HelloComponent', () => {
  let component: HelloComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HelloComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [HelloComponent],
      // setups automatically all dependecies of the component as mock objects
      providers: moqInjectorProviders(HelloComponent)
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HelloComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('check subscribeEmail function has value', fakeAsync(() => {
    const injector = TestBed.get(Injector);

    // sets mock behaviour
    resolveMock(HttpClient, injector)
      // if jsonp is invoked with first parameter with email substring
      .setup(instance => instance.jsonp(It.Is<string>(url => url.indexOf('me@gmail.com') > 1), 'c'))
      // only in this case return a cold observable
      .returns(cold("a", {a: {result: "success"}}));

    const email = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.email-input')).nativeElement;
    // sets email value
    email.value = 'me@gmail.com';
    // notifies angualr that element has changed
    email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    const subscribeButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.subscribe'));
    subscribeButton.triggerEventHandler('click', {});

    // flush the observable of jsonp
    getTestScheduler().flush();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.submitted).toBe(true);
  }));

  it('sets error when server returns an error', fakeAsync(() => {
    const injector = TestBed.get(Injector);
    const msg = "erorr message";

    resolveMock(HttpClient, injector)
      .setup(instance => instance.jsonp(It.Is<string>(url => url.indexOf('me@gmail.com') > 1), 'c'))
      .returns(cold("a", {a: {result: "error", msg}}));

    const email = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.email-input')).nativeElement;
    email.value = 'me@gmail.com';
    email.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    const subscribeButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.subscribe'));
    subscribeButton.triggerEventHandler('click', {});

    getTestScheduler().flush();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.error).toEqual(msg);
  }));
});
```

[Here you can find an working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-vx1pbs)

Please, noticed the I used some extra libs like jasmine-marbles to fake observables or moq.ts to mock HttpClient