# How to test a JSONP method in a service - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am making a simple email subscription application for which I have written tests and things went fine as for now.

In order to make things simple, I wish to explain the exact part where I am facing the issue.

**my-service.ts** :

```
export class MyService {

  mailChimpEndpoint =
    'https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&amp;id=01681f1b55&amp';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  submitForm(email: string){

        const params = new HttpParams()

        .set('EMAIL', email)
        .set('subscribe','Subscribe')
        .set('b_aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d_01681f1b55','')

        const mailChimpUrl = this.mailChimpEndpoint + params.toString();

        return this._http.jsonp<MailChimpResponse>(mailChimpUrl, 'c')
  }

}
```

> The above is a simple method in a service that calls an api

Link to the service file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-imniaf?file=app%2Fmy-service.ts

Now I am trying to write a test case for the above method `submitForm` in

**my-service.spec.ts**

```
  it('check subscribeEmail function has been called in service', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const service = TestBed.get(MyService);
    service.submitForm('test@gmail.com').subscribe(
        response => {
            expect(response).toEqual(mockServiceData);
        }
    )

    const reqMock = httpTestingController.expectOne(request => request.url === mailChimpEndpoint);
    expect(reqMock.request.method).toBe('GET');
    reqMock.flush(mockServiceData);
  });
```

Link to this spec file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-imniaf?file=app%2Fmy-service.spec.ts

This is where I am getting stucked and the above code throws the error as,

> **Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match by function:
>   ", found none.**

The complete working stackblitz link:

> [**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-ajoov8**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-ajoov8)

Please help me to pass this test as success.

Comment: it was all minor code issues, I have fixed them all. Be more cautious about it ;) and read my article for more testing scenarios https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7 . Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [working demo code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-dn5yad?file=app/my-service.spec.ts)

1. You should have removed `useClass` :)
2. Corrected `mailChimpEndpoint` value.
3. corrected `expect(reqMock.request.method).toBe('JSONP');`
4. Removed `done: DoneFn`.

```
  it('check subscribeEmail function has been called in service', () => {
    const service = TestBed.get(MyService);
    service.submitForm('test@gmail.com').subscribe(
        response => {
            console.log(response)
            expect(response).toEqual(mockServiceData);
        }
    )

    const reqMock = httpTestingController.expectOne(req => req.url === mailChimpEndpoint);
    expect(reqMock.request.method).toBe('JSONP');
    reqMock.flush(mockServiceData);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the letting me know what I did wrong in the test.. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` should be a spy, then you can assert it.

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  // add this to the definition of the testing module
  providers: [{
    provide: HttpClient,
    useValue: {
      jsonp: jasmine.createSpy('httpClient.jsonp'),
    }
  }]
})
```

and then in the test

```js
  it('check subscribeEmail function has been called in service', (done: DoneFn) => {
    const service = TestBed.get(MyService);
    const httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);

    const expected: any = Symbol();
    (httpClient.jsonp as any).and.returnValue(expected);

    const actual = service.submitForm('test@gmail.com');
    expect(actual).toBe(expected);
    expect(httpClient.jsonp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(provideValueHere, 'c');
  });
```

---

and now your test should be like that:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyService } from './my-service';

describe('MyService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
        {
          provide: HttpClient,
          useValue: {
            jsonp: jasmine.createSpy('httpClient.jsonp'),
          }
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents());

  it('check subscribeEmail function has been called in service', () => {
    const httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    const service = TestBed.get(MyService);

    const expected: any = Symbol();
    (httpClient.jsonp as any).and.returnValue(expected);

    const actual = service.submitForm('test@gmail.com');
    expect(actual).toBe(expected);
    expect(httpClient.jsonp).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&amp;id=01681f1b55&ampEMAIL=test@gmail.com&subscribe=Subscribe&b_aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d_01681f1b55=', 'c');
  });
});
```

Comment: As per your solution, I have included the changes here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-bkejqt but it results in new issue..

Comment: added the solution - simply copy paste it to replace the test in your stackblitz.

Comment: This gives the error as ```Expected spy httpClient.jsonp to have been called with [ 'https://gmail.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d&amp;id=01681f1b55&ampEMAIL=test@gmail.com&subscribe=Subscribe&b_aaa7182511d7bd278fb9d510d_01681f1b55=', 'c' ] but actual calls were [ 'EMAIL=test@gmail.com&=', 'c' ].``` ..

Comment: have you changed the source code of the service? Looks like HttpParams was removed. Here is a fork of your stackbliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-kvhwud?file=app%2Fmy-service.spec.ts

Comment: In real application I am facing this issue.. Can you guess what would be the issue? I have included all the code you given above..

Comment: check this part in the real app: https://take.ms/OvdjD, or simply change assertion in the test to `'EMAIL=test@gmail.com&=', 'c'` if it's expected.

Comment: Might you mark the answer as the right one if it fits?