# How to cover the test for form control in angular? (Stackblitz attached)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am making a simple application which has an input field and a button and on click of the button an api call was made and respective response is fetched.

Everything working fine with this.

**Things done as of now:** I am making a validation and display the error message via a function like,

**hello.component.ts**:

```
controlErrors(formControl: AbstractControl | FormControl): string {
    if (
      formControl &&
      formControl.touched &&
      formControl.invalid &&
      formControl.errors
    ) {
      return Object.keys(formControl.errors)[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And in `HTML` template adding the validation message like,

**hello.component.html**:

```
  <form [formGroup]="userForm" novalidate>
      <input
        class="email-input mat-body-1"
        type="email"
        formControlName="email"
      />
      <button class="subscribe mat-body-2" [disabled]="userForm.invalid || submitted" (click)="subscribeEmail()">
        Subscribe
      </button>
      <span *ngIf="controlErrors(userForm.get('email')); let error">{{
        error
      }}</span>
    </form>
```

I have written test case to cover the control errors (as other test were already covered) like,

**hello.component.spec.ts**:

```
  describe('controlErrors', () => {

    it('should return null if !formControl', () => {
      const result = component.controlErrors(null);
      expect(result).toBeNull();
    });

    it('should return null if formControl is untouched', () => {
      const formControl = new FormControl();
      const result = component.controlErrors(formControl);
      expect(result).toBeNull();
    });

  });
```

**Issue:** And the issue is while running the test coverage it is showing that the **branch (yellow highlighted) and statement(red highlighted) not covered** like,

[image]

Requirement: Kindly please help me to cover these tests of control errors completely so that this spec file will have 100% test coverage.

**Working test case written stackblitz:** **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-x5rx7s**

As I am a beginner in angular unit testing please guide me with right solution.

Big thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Based on the comment by @Marc, I have tried like,

```
it('should return invalid formControl if touched with invalid email', () => {
  const formControl = new FormControl('test');
  formControl.touched;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const result = component.controlErrors(formControl);
  expect(result).toBeNull();
});
```

But it results in the same issue like the above screenshot.. Can anyone please help me how should I need to achieve the result of full test coverage?

Comment: Your testing is very good. I think that your tests covers the happy path. What you can do: you can set an invalid input (email)  and set this input to touched. After that you can trigger fixture.detectChanges();

Comment: @Marc, Thanks for your reply .. Can you give a working solution for it please?